# issue with a selector

Tags: ios

I'm running into problems with a selector.  I'm trying to dynamically name an array, winnerArray1, winnerArray2, winnerArray3, etc.

The variable `someVariable` is in a loop that increases so that will get incremented.

I get unrecognized selector sent to instance

```
int someVariable = 1;
NSArray  *winnerArray;
NSString *tempLoopString;


while(someVariable < 4){
        tempLoopString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"winnerArray%d", someVariable];
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(tempLoopString);
        winnerArray = [self performSelector:selector];  



        if ([winnerArray do_stuff]) {

            do stuff here
        }
  someVariable++
```

}

Comment: Which specific selector?Not enought code to help you.Provide tempLopingString,please

Comment: Do you actually have methods defined on that class with names like `-winnerArray1`, `-winnerArray2`, etc. that return instances of `NSArray`?

Comment: Also, there is no method named `do_stuff` on `NSArray`, so if your code literally looks like that, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: winnerArray1, winnerArray2 and so on are NSArrays not methods.  Since i'm doing same thing for multiple NSArrays i want to use a selector. I'm not using do_stuff but             if ([winnerArray containsObject:tempNumber]) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer to a variable by name like that.

You should look into using key value coding. With that, you can interrogate a property of some object using the method valueForKey: